# Simple homomorphism Question: Prove that $φ(s)$ is a reflection

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups, group-homomorphism

Let r ∈ D20 be an element of order 20 and let s ∈ D20 be a reflection. Suppose that φ : D20 → D20 is a homomorphism such that φ(r) = r^12

Prove that $φ(s)$ is a reflection

Comment: I take it $D_{20}$ is the group of symmetries of the regular $20$-gon? I only ask because some use this notation for symmetries of the regular $10$-gon.

Comment: Im sorry!  I am one of those who use it as the group of symmetries of the regular 10-gon

Comment: OK, then I must be confused; you say *Let* $r \in D_{20}$ *be an element of order* $20$, but $D_{20}$ isn't cyclic; do you mean that the group has order $20$, or do you really mean an element with order $20$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $s^2=1$ we have $\phi(s)^2=\phi(s^2)=\phi(1)=1$. Hence $\phi(s)$ is a reflection (possibly the trivial one).